# Android/IOS push notification from PHP adding emoji's

Tags: php, android, ios

I have a class in php that sends push notification to android/IOS users of the app through web. Now I need to add emoji's to title/body of the push notification payload, but no luck doing so.

I've already tried convert encoding to UTF-8, I've tried using [this](https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji) library and I've tried replacing \\ to \ (json_encode function adds \\ instead of \ on e.g     \xC2\xA9 becomes \\xC2\\xA9).

Here's my code :

```
public function sendPush($payload)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->base_url . "/push");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'X-AUTH-TOKEN: 94h4f5RCDSEYKYqXDHTk';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

That's push function, and here's the .tpl where I get the data from web.

```
<?php
include(SITE_ROOT . '/core/admin/logo.class.php');

if (isset($_POST['push-button'])) {
    if (
        isset($_POST['push-title'])
        && isset($_POST['push-body'])
        && isset($_POST['push-city'])
        && isset($_POST['push-url'])
        && isset($_POST['push-platform'])
    ) {
        $push = new Push();

        $title = $_POST['push-title'];
        $body = $_POST['push-body'];
        $url = $_POST['push-url'];
        $platform = $_POST['push-platform'];
        $cities = $_POST['push-city'];

        $payload = [
            'title'  => $title,
            'body'   => $body,
            'url'    => $url,
            'cities' => [
                $cities
            ]
        ];

        if ($platform === 'all') {
            $responses_ios = json_decode($push->sendPush($payload), true);
            $responses_android = json_decode($push->sendPushAndroid($payload), true);
        } elseif ($platform === 'ios') {
            $responses_ios = json_decode($push->sendPush($payload), true);
        } elseif ($platform === 'android') {
            $responses_android = json_decode($push->sendPushAndroid($payload), true);
        }

        // $devices = '';

        // var_dump($responses);

        // foreach ($responses_ios as $response) {
        //     $devices .= $response . "<br>";
        // }

        $message = '<span class="message"><strong>PUSH-notiser har skickats</strong></span>';

        unset($_SESSION['message']);

    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PUSH - Administration</title>
    <?php include(SITE_ROOT . '/views/admin/meta.tpl'); ?>
</head>

<body class="page-admin">
    <?php include(SITE_ROOT . '/views/admin/header.tpl'); ?>
    <?php include(SITE_ROOT . '/views/admin/navigation.tpl'); ?>

    <p class="shoutout p-45 text-center">Skicka PUSH-meddelanden till användare i en stad</p>

    <?php echo $message; ?>

    <section class="wrapper">
        <section class="container centered">
            <section class="col-3-5">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
                    <section class="row">
                        <span class="input-title">Välj stad</span>

                        <span class="input-field">
                            <select name="push-city">
                              <option value="all">Alla</option>
                                <?php
                                $cities = $app->get_page_list('city');
                                foreach ($cities as $city) {
                                    echo '<option value=' . $city['page_name'] . ' />' . $city['page_name'] . '</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </span>
                    </section>

                    <section class="row">
                        <span class="input-title">Titel</span>

                        <span class="input-field">
                            <input type="text" name="push-title" class="slug" placeholder="Titel på meddelande"
                                   required/>
                        </span>
                    </section>

                    <section class="row">
                        <span class="input-title">Meddelande</span>

                        <span class="input-field">
                            <textarea name="push-body" class="slug" placeholder="Meddelande" required></textarea>
                        </span>
                    </section>

                    <section class="row">
                        <span class="input-title">URL</span>

                        <span class="input-field">
                            <input type="text" name="push-url" class="slug" placeholder="URL att skicka med" required/>
                        </span>
                    </section>

                    <section class="row">
                        <span class="input-title">Plattform</span>
                        <span class="input-field">
                            <input type="radio" name="push-platform" class="slug"
                                   placeholder="Välj plattform att skicka till"
                                   value="all" checked required/>Alla
                            <input type="radio" name="push-platform" class="slug"
                                   placeholder="Välj plattform att skicka till"
                                   value="ios" required/>iOS
                            <input type="radio" name="push-platform" class="slug"
                                   placeholder="Välj plattform att skicka till"
                                   value="android" required/>Android
                        </span>
                    </section>
                    <section class="row" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                        <input type="submit" class="button-large-2 button-no-g" name="push-button"
                               value="Skicka PUSH-notis"/>
                    </section>
                </form>

            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
    <?php include(SITE_ROOT . '/views/admin/emoji.tpl'); ?>
    <?php include(SITE_ROOT . '/views/admin/footer.tpl'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I get from echo/var_dump on title/body

```
 string(13) "test \xC2\xA9" string(13) "test \xC2\xA9"
```

Those 2 \xC2\xA9 should be copyright signs.